# My brake lever is coming loose from my handle bars; how can I tighten it?

Tags: maintenance, handlebars, brakes

I have a road bike with drop bars, and the left brake lever is slightly loose - it can rotate a few degrees around the handle bar from side to side. How can I tighten it? Is it possible to do so without unwrapping the handle bars?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The answer the the last question AFAIK is "probably not", but can we get more information about your levers, or a picture of the levers and bars?

Comment: I own shimano 105 brakes and I can tighten them without unwrapping anything. Only a little rubber to lift. What brakes do you have?

Comment: @Neil Done and done. I can't see any kind of screw that might be used to tighten them to the handle bars.

Comment: On some models you squeeze the handle and run a screwdriver down through middle.  I'm thinking you may have to unhook the cable first.

Comment: @Daniel I can see a little "T" when I remove the little black cap from the front of the lever. It doesn't appear to be a screw. Photo coming.

Comment: After trying to get a photo, I realized the "T" was set back inside a little hex socket, and that it is responsible for tightening the lever to the bar. I couldn't tell with a flashlight because the edges were in shadow. Posted my photo as an answer below, thanks guys. Edits to my answer for any specific terminology would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen the mechanic tightening the levers through the handle on someone's bike when I was on my tour in June, but I didn't pay real close attention to the details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be removing the cap from the front of the lever, a hex socket is revealed through a small opening, which can be tightened to snug the lever to the handle bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Early Shimano 105s leavers all you have to do is:

1. 'slack' off the Brake callipers by pushing the little leaver on the brakes(not leavers on bars) to full open (as if you need to take the wheels off).
2. Stand in front of the handle bars and pull the leavers fully as if braking and look in to the leavers! inside you will see a HEX nut (5mm) tighten and your ready to go!